# How to have a script work with "$@" or a default list of parameters while not breaking paths with whitespace?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I want a script that will run another utility over some default paths if no parameters are passed to it; ideally I want this safe for paths that contain spaces.

So far I have `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
base=$(dirname "$0")
exec touch "${@:-"$base/aaa" "$base/bbb"}"
```

If I put this into a folder called "foo bar" and run it as:

> ```
> foo\ bar/script.sh
> ```

I want it to should end up doing:

```
touch foo\ bar/aaa foo\ bar/bbb
```

i.e. create files "aaa" and "bbb" under "foo bar", the directory in which the script is located.

Instead I get the error

> touch: cannot touch 'foo bar/aaa foo bar/bbb': No such file or directory

(If I pass in parameters to the script it seems to work fine. Presumably removing the outer quotes in the last command would reverse my cases.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears you can't set default parameters in an expansion of `${@:-...}`, and `"${@:-"$base/aaa" "$base/bbb"}"` is expanded as a single string.

If you want to set default parameters you might want to do this:

```
base=$(dirname -- "$0")
# test explicitly for no parameters, and set them.
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    set -- "$base/aaa" "$base/bbb"
fi
```

Then, the `"$@"` magically quoted parameter substitution can happen unabated:

```
touch -- "$@"
```

Comment: @Jesse_b It's a minor change and the rest works the same, but yes, that made it work for me

Comment: (I like to stick to being dash-compatible if possible for scripts so as to not have to pull in bash into Docker images unnecessarily.)

Comment: About that first sentence, `set --; echo ${@:-default}; set -- a b; echo ${@:-default};` works (i.e. prints `default` and then `a b`) in all shells I tried. Though I don't think you should be able to give a list as a default value, the syntax only mentions a single _word_ there.

Comment: Sorry, but it is possible to use several parameters in a default expansion, but only with shells that have arrays. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493990/265604)

Comment: @ilkkachu - I mean in the context of my question I understood that sentence as “it’s impossible to do that and have it expand as OP wants”

Comment: @ilkkachu You could be able to use a list as a default value, provided you don't quote the whole expansion -- `set --; printf '<%s>\n' ${1-"x      y" "z"}` (the *unquoted* part of the replacement word would be IFS-split+globbed, except in `zsh` in non-compat mode). Of course, you cannot do that without having `$1` itself split+globbed if defined.

Comment: @UncleBilly, ungh, that works but it seems somewhat horrible. (Because of the thing with `$1` being left unquoted, if for no other reason)

Comment: @ilkkachu you can make it work by using a temp var. `a=${1+--}; printf '<%s>\n' touch ${a:- -- "1st dflt" "2nd dflt"} "$@"` will pass `$1`, `$2`, ... to `printf` if `$1` is defined (even if empty), and `1st dflt` and `2nd dflt` if not. All of this is of course pointless; `test "$#" = 0 && set -- "1st dflt" "2nd dflt"` as in this answer is the best and simplest.

Comment: You are missing some `"` in the code. To be safe make the first line `base="$(dirname -- "$0")"`

Comment: That's not strictly required. Variable assignments are not subject to word splitting and pathname expansion. You could do `a=*` and have a literal asterisk not a list of files. Of course, you must quote `"$a"` every time you *use* the variable.

Answer (score 6):

It IS possible to use several parameters in a default expansion `${@-...}`,

like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
base=$(dirname "$0")
arr=("$base/aaa" "$base/bbb")

touch "${@:-"${arr[@]}"}"
```

But only on shells that have arrays (ksh, zsh, bash, etc.).